# Why xslt creats a new table but not uses the one of the template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file like this

```
<Root>
 ...
 <x></x>
 <node>
  ...
  <x></x>
  <y></y>
 </node>
</Root>
```

My xslt is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <!-- proceed the treatment of the statement before x-->
 <tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates match="Root/x"/>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates match="Root"/>
 </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x">
  ...
</xsl:template match="x">

<xsl:template match="Root">
 <!--Proceed the treatment of the statement before x-->
 <tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates match="x"/>
 </tr>
 <!--Deal with y-->
```

The template which matches "/" will create a table and fill it with all the nodes in the xml file. x can appear in every element like "node" and maybe different each time. "node" can also appear several times with different content.

But when I use this xslt, after dealing with x, it creates a new table for the elements after x, So node will be in a new table and also for y.

Does anyone know how to do? Thank u

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you give an example of what XML output you are trying to get?

Comment: what is the match="x" template doing? I don't see any <table> in your code so I'm wondering where you create the table??

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates match="x"/>  is incorrect syntax. Must be: <xsl:apply-templates select="x"/>  . Please, correct. Also, please, give a more meaningful example. The current formulation of the problem is very unclear and begs for a downvote.

Comment: Good point, Dimitre. Looks like this could already be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are processing stuff in your "/" template, then processing it all again in the "Root" template, since the "/" template explicitly applies the Root template as well.

Try deleting the definition of the "/" template and just doing all the work in the template for "Root"

Answer (score 0):

To divo,

match="x" template deals with the child elements of "x". Sorry for making you misunderstand, i just ignored the code for creating the table. The table is created in the match="/" template. Thanks